# When a Particular file is uploaded in blob storage trigger will invoke data pipeline

Tags: azure

I want to solve a scenario where when a particular file is uploaded into the blob storage, trigger is invoked and pipeline runs.

I tried event based triggers but I don't know how to tackle this scenario.

Comment: What pipeline?.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduce same in my environment . I got this output.

First create a Blob event trigger .

> **Note:**
>
> - **Blob path begins with**('/Container_Name/') – Receives events form container.
> - **Blob path begins with**('/Container_Name/Folder_Name') – Receives events form container_name container and folder_name folder.

[image]

**Data preview:**

[image]

- **Continue and click on OK.**

If you created a parameter. For example in my scenario, I created a parameter called `file_name`   directly you can pass the value inside the parameter by using `@triggerBody().fileName` -> Publish the pipeline.

[image]

For more information follow this [reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RXEHrET9dUc).